# Creating unique index that accept multiple null values with hibernate

Tags: sql, hibernate, jpa

I have a column that is unique and accepts null values.

I can do `@COLUMN(unique = true, nullable = true)` but it accepts 1 null value only which is not my goal.

I tried this in SQL and it worked:

```
Create UNIQUE INDEX INDEX_NAME ON TABLE(COLUMN) EXCLUDE NULL KEYS
```

My question is how can I do this using hibernate annotation or are there any workarounds to do this?

Comment: Which DBMS product supports that syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not possible with Hibernate.

In general using Hibernate to generate the database objects is a good idea for small or demo projects. In real world projects where the database is important it mostly better to write the SQL statements yourself.

For database migrations Flyway or Liquibase are two great tools.